# Bundled jar is not executable - jar2app

Tags: java, macos, deployment, jar, packaging

I created a .app for Mac with jar2app, but by default it is not executable. To execute I must first enter some commands in terminal. However, since we want to ship this .app to users, we want to make it executable by default. What do I need to do for that? Adapting info.plist or JavaAppLauncher?

Comment: What steps do you have to execute? Do you have to execute the steps the first time you try to execute then every time after it just executes or do you have to run them every time you try to execute the app?

Comment: chmod +x /Contents/MacOS/JavaAppLauncher

Comment: I only need to do that once after download

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this without needing to use third-party apps:

- Create an executable jar file
- Launch AppleScript editor
- Write the following:

```
 --do shell script "java -jar /Contents/execute.jar"
```

The line is commented out because the jar is not yet in the folder with the script.

Save as application. Right Click on the .app file it created and select 'Show Package Contents'. Drag the .jar file to the contents. (Before dragging the jar file, chmod it so that it has 777, i.e chmod 777 execute.jar) Finally, go to Resources -> Scripts -> main.scpt and edit it. Now remove the comment, i.e the double dash (--), and replace execute.jar with the name of your jar file, compile and save.

Comment: Hi, this leads to Error: Unable to access jarfile /Contents/Java/Updater.jar (I have included a Subfolder "Java" to store my JAR's